# Set/change text weight within the Text property of a TextBlock

Tags: wpf, xaml, textblock

I would like to be able to change the weight of text (e.g. change from Normal to Bold and back again) within the `Text` property string of a `TextBlock` (presumably using some control character set). Is this even possible?

Comment: @H.B. like `<TextBlock Text="This is <b>special</b> text" />` (if it did things HTML-like)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextBLock.Text` creates a single `Run`, you set custom [`Inlines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.inlines.aspx) instead:

```
<TextBlock>
    Text with <Bold>bold</Bold> within.
<TextBlock>
```

Obviously it no longer uses the `Text` property.

Comment: I like this answer better for inlines, I must not have understood at first glance. +1

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about something like this?

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="Hey it's Normal Text"/>
    <Run Text="Hey it's Bold Text" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    <Run Text="Hey it's Colored Text" Foreground="Green"/>
</TextBlock>
```